# Merging duplicated protected questions

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I found two duplicated questions which are protected:

['Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object' error during postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832470)
[ASP.NET MS11-100: how can I change the limit on the maximum number of posted form values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684049)

Is it possible to merge them together?
Since both of them are protected I cannot close any of them as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> Since both of them are protected I cannot close any of them as a duplicate.

I just missed the action links on the page - I *can* close as duplicate.